# Rails upgrade to 3.2 routes/locale fails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, locale, rails-i18n

I have recently upgraded a project to Rails 3.2 from 3.1 and have been stuck trying to figure out why the routing is not playing nicely with devise.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `locale' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:xxxxx>:
```

This is on the new ([1](https://gist.github.com/yuric/5334979#file-gistfile1-rb-L7))Journey routing engine. The issue for now is with Devise only other modules are not erroring. I can tell the issue is within my use of scope. It works if I get ready of the scope.

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
    ...
end
```

([1](https://gist.github.com/yuric/5334979#file-gistfile1-rb-L7)) Line 7 (133). Please see trace and [Journey line error in context here.](https://gist.github.com/yuric/5334979#file-gistfile1-rb-L7)

Any advice and guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Try to put :locale in a :constraints hash:

```
scope "(:locale)", :constraints => {:locale => /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/}
```

I think it will help for more problems too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html